# do-while loop only runs once

Tags: php, class, while-loop, do-while, factorial

I am trying to make a simple while loop using a class to get the factorial of a number.  However, for some reason, the while loop is only returning the value after it has run once.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    class Factorial {
      public function calculate($int){
             $intStep = $int-1;
                     do {
                        $int*=$intStep;
                        $int--;
                        return $int;
                       } while($int>0);    
              if (!is_int($int)){
                 echo "entry is not a number";
                 }
              }
            }

$factorial = new Factorial;
echo $factorial->calculate(5);
```

Comment: The `return $int;` line is causing the function to, well, _return_ that value. The function doesn't continue executing when you return from it.

Comment: The word `return` means exit the function. This is why your loop only runs once, because you are exiting the function in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code:

1. `return $int;` is run inside the do while loop, which means it'll only ever run once.
2. You're decrementing `$int` instead of `$intStep`
3. You're checking if `$int` is below zero instead of `$intStep`

Here's your code with all of these problems fixed, it works and returns 15:

```
class Factorial {

    public function calculate ($int) {
        if (!is_int($int)) {
            echo "entry is not a number";
        }
        $intStep = $int - 1;
        do {
            $int += $intStep;
            $intStep--;
        } while ($intStep > 0);
        return $int;
    }
}

$factorial = new Factorial;
echo $factorial->calculate(5);
```

[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/TSbAs)

Comment: Hey David, 

I was trying to get the factorial of the number.  the output in this case should be 120.  (5*4*3*2*1).  However, the 3 issues you pointed out to me were exactly what was wrong with the code and exactly what I needed to figure it out.  Now that you mention the issues I'm like "F**k how did I not notice this? What silly mistakes!" I just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out... Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return from your function until your result is ready. Since you return early, you won't finish your calculation.

In general, your life will be easier if you learn how to debug. For PHP, the easiest way would be to `echo` stuff throughout your code. If you put `echo $int` inside of your loop it would be more obvious to you what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 <?php
            class Factorial {
              public function calculate($num){
          $Factorial = 1;
          $i =1;
                             do{
                              $Factorial *= $i;
                              $i++;
                            }while($i<=$num);
                          return $Factorial;     

                      }
                    }
        $factorial = new Factorial;
        echo $factorial->calculate(5);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Factorial ? Maybe the following code is what you want:

Don't forget negative Numbers.

```
class Factorial {

    public function calculate ($int) {
        if (!is_int($int)) {
            echo "entry is not a number";
        }
        if ($int == 0 || $int == 1) {
            $result = 1;
        } else if ($int < 0) {
            $result = $this->calculate($int + 1) * $int;
        } else {
            $result = $this->calculate($int - 1) * $int;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$factorial = new Factorial;
echo $factorial->calculate(-4);
```